# Versioning of lists for analysis

Tags: list, versioning, powerbi

### Update

Well, I found a partial solution to my question. So, I have to update it. The way to extract information for my purpose is by turning on versioning. However, I am still not sure how to extract the information I need without having to go through each element and doing it manually.

---

My company intends to use data in our Sharepoint lists for analysis With Power BI. However, some of the data they need require me to know the history of how many times and to what various columns have been changed. So, for instance, how many times have a column been changed to option 2 this year (for each element)? Or, how often have I changed the text in column 3?

How can I extract this data? Where can I find tutorials on how to do this online?